# MySQL Insert Query failed with no error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, insert

I have an issue with a SQL insert query to my database. I have checked the connection with the database, and it seems to work fine. When I submit the form, I get no error message, and it seems like it inserts the rows into  my table, but nothing happens.

This is the code for the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `***`.`employee` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Updated code for employee.php file which is called upon by the control panel:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $dbhost = '****';
    $dbuser = '****';
    $dbpass = '****';
    $dbname = '****';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(!$conn){
       die(mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['fullname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `employee`  (`email`,`name`) VALUES ('$email','$name')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    mysqli_close($conn);

    else{
?>


    <form id="regForm" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
        <input name="register" type="submit" id="register" value="Register" ></button>
    </form>


<?php } ?>
```

I also have a jquery script that changes the content, and might cause issues:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#cpnav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#cpcon').load('../cp/' + page + '.php');
    return false;
    });
});
```

This is the html for the control panel, and employee is a button in the control panel which links to the registration form:

```
<ul id="cpnav"> 
<li><a href="employee">Add Employee</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried mysqli aswell, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Wait, where does the form submit? If `$_PHP_SELF` isn't set to `employee.php`, nothing is going to happen. Is `$_PHP_SELF` even set? You aren't even `echo`-ing it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your form's action attribute is all kinds of wrong and given how you're injecting the form into the page, you won't be able to control the value properly from the `employee.php` script.

Here's what I'd do...

1. Ignore the `action` attribute in your script (ie, leave it blank)

   ```
   <form id="regForm" method="post" action="">
   ```
2. Fix up the form action in JavaScript

   ```
   var page = $(this).attr('href'),
       path = '../cp/' + page + '.php';
   $('#cpcon').load(path, function() {
       $('#regForm').attr('action', path);
   });
   ```

Now, chances are this is going to work in that your `INSERT` statement will (probably) execute. However, you will only see a blank page. You might want to redirect to a success page or something after successfully updating the database.

---

Now let me tell you about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)...

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($conn->errno) {
    throw new Exception($conn->error, $conn->errno);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `employee` (`email`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)');
if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($conn->error, $conn->errno);
}
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
}

// here's where you would do some sort of redirect
header('Location: success.php?employee_id=' . $conn->insert_id);
exit;
```